# How to send a variable outside a form to a PHP file using a form?

Tags: php, variables, get, send

I've got a page where I have a form that gets sent on to a php file that renders an email with the information and sends it on.

However, there are variables in the url (form.php?a=12&b=hello) that I also need to send.

I don't like the idea of having a hidden input field with this value or something like this. Is there a way to send it in a way that I can just $_REQUEST($a) and $_REQUEST($b) in the email rendering script?

Comment: why don't you "like the idea"? it's a good one ... simple too.

Comment: I guess I just don't like hacks too much.

Comment: How is a hidden field a hack?

Comment: Well, it's an input field that isn't for inputing..

Comment: That's just wrong, and a little funny. That's what they were created for. Variables that do not require user intervention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can. `$_REQUEST` contains both the `$_POST` and `$_GET` data, so you were already on the right track;

```
$_REQUEST['a']; // from the url
$_REQUEST['field_1']; // posted from <input name="field_1" />
```

Comment: he specifically said it's not in the form. so how would it end up in $_REQUEST if it's not in the form nor in the url?

Comment: Well, if it's in the URL, and you're not modifying it (in other words `action=""`), they're still in the URL after posting.